# Banned for faulty review question

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I just got [this review question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12402304) on Stack Overflow that is clearly either too broad or off-topic for asking for an off-site resource. But when I flagged the question I failed the audit, and now I can't review any more for a couple of days.

Is there any way to undo this review ban?

Comment: No, you made a mistake (not the only one as review bans don't happen after only one incident). Now you need to reflect on that and learn from it. It's only two days after all.

Comment: Still flagged it, because you were right. Do note that you don't get a review ban because of one failed audit.

Comment: Bad review.  Happens sometimes.  Don't sweat it, just enjoy the break.